# Pulling lagged data from a particular season but only for specific data sets as indicated by variable in R

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

My original inquiry came from this question: [Pulling lagged data but only for a particular season in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69901914/pulling-lagged-data-but-only-for-a-particular-season-in-r)

This answered my question for specific data frames; however, now I have a large aggregated data frame and need to add a line of code that accounts for each individual dataset (Lake_name).

Here is my data :

```
   SeasonYear       change   Lake_name
1  winter2020  0.007877245   AlanHenry
2  spring2020  0.058515310   AlanHenry
3  summer2020  0.013850687   AlanHenry
4    fall2020 -0.071774781   AlanHenry
5  winter2021 -0.040268206   AlanHenry
6  spring2021 -0.020803715   AlanHenry
7  summer2021  0.181610974   AlanHenry
8  winter2020 -0.029708916     Amistad
9  spring2020 -0.063310371     Amistad
10 summer2020 -0.054231575     Amistad
11   fall2020  0.016057252     Amistad
12 winter2021  0.011785717     Amistad
13 spring2021 -0.030677687     Amistad
14 summer2021 -0.015691720     Amistad
15 winter2020 -0.011974634 AmonGCarter
16 spring2020  0.168774234 AmonGCarter
17 summer2020 -0.041486735 AmonGCarter
18   fall2020 -0.095134974 AmonGCarter
19 winter2021 -0.030310177 AmonGCarter
20 spring2021  0.033528325 AmonGCarter
```

I am trying to build a function that takes the lag from the previous spring (see previous post) but also accounts for each lake. If I separate it out individually, I can do this but I have a pretty large data set and this would take a long time to do. Here is the code I am trying to do this with (modified from the post I referenced):

```
library(dplyr)
lag_spring <- function(x, y, n = 1) {
  data.frame(x = x, season_year = y) %>% 
    group_by(Lake_name) %>%
    tidyr::extract(season_year, into = c("season", "year"), regex = "^(.+?)(\\d{4})$") %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    mutate(springmean = x[season == "spring"]) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(season) %>%
    mutate(lag = ifelse(!season %in% c("summer", "fall"), lag(springmean, n = n), lag(springmean, n = n - 1))) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    pull(lag)
}
```

I tried to add the `group_by(Lake_name)` to do this within each lake but when I run the code:

```
data %>%  mutate(springlag = lag_spring(change, SeasonYear,n=1),
         springlag2 = lag_spring(change, SeasonYear,n=2),
         springlag3 = lag_spring(change, SeasonYear,n=3))
```

I get this error:

> Error: Problem with mutate() input springlag.
> x Must group by variables found in .data.
> Column Lake_name is not found.
> i Input springlag is lag_spring(change, SeasonYear, n = 1)

Can someone help modify the code I got earlier to get the "springlag" but include a line within dplyr that only does this within each individual lake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to change the function. You could achieve your desired result with a `group_by` before the `mutate` where you compute the lag:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

lag_spring <- function(x, y, n = 1) {
  data.frame(x = x, season_year = y) %>%
    tidyr::extract(season_year, into = c("season", "year"), regex = "^(.+?)(\\d{4})$") %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    mutate(springmean = if (any(season == "spring")) x[season == "spring"] else NA) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(season) %>%
    mutate(lag = ifelse(!season %in% c("summer", "fall"), lag(springmean, n = n), lag(springmean, n = n - 1))) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    pull(lag)
}

dd %>%
  group_by(Lake_name) %>%
  mutate(lag = lag_spring(change, SeasonYear))
#> # A tibble: 20 × 4
#> # Groups:   Lake_name [3]
#>    SeasonYear   change Lake_name       lag
#>    <chr>         <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>
#>  1 winter2020  0.00788 AlanHenry   NA     
#>  2 spring2020  0.0585  AlanHenry   NA     
#>  3 summer2020  0.0139  AlanHenry    0.0585
#>  4 fall2020   -0.0718  AlanHenry    0.0585
#>  5 winter2021 -0.0403  AlanHenry    0.0585
#>  6 spring2021 -0.0208  AlanHenry    0.0585
#>  7 summer2021  0.182   AlanHenry   -0.0208
#>  8 winter2020 -0.0297  Amistad     NA     
#>  9 spring2020 -0.0633  Amistad     NA     
#> 10 summer2020 -0.0542  Amistad     -0.0633
#> 11 fall2020    0.0161  Amistad     -0.0633
#> 12 winter2021  0.0118  Amistad     -0.0633
#> 13 spring2021 -0.0307  Amistad     -0.0633
#> 14 summer2021 -0.0157  Amistad     -0.0307
#> 15 winter2020 -0.0120  AmonGCarter NA     
#> 16 spring2020  0.169   AmonGCarter NA     
#> 17 summer2020 -0.0415  AmonGCarter  0.169 
#> 18 fall2020   -0.0951  AmonGCarter  0.169 
#> 19 winter2021 -0.0303  AmonGCarter  0.169 
#> 20 spring2021  0.0335  AmonGCarter  0.169
```

**DATA**

```
dd <- structure(list(SeasonYear = c(
  "winter2020", "spring2020", "summer2020",
  "fall2020", "winter2021", "spring2021", "summer2021", "winter2020",
  "spring2020", "summer2020", "fall2020", "winter2021", "spring2021",
  "summer2021", "winter2020", "spring2020", "summer2020", "fall2020",
  "winter2021", "spring2021"
), change = c(
  0.007877245, 0.05851531,
  0.013850687, -0.071774781, -0.040268206, -0.020803715, 0.181610974,
  -0.029708916, -0.063310371, -0.054231575, 0.016057252, 0.011785717,
  -0.030677687, -0.01569172, -0.011974634, 0.168774234, -0.041486735,
  -0.095134974, -0.030310177, 0.033528325
), Lake_name = c(
  "AlanHenry",
  "AlanHenry", "AlanHenry", "AlanHenry", "AlanHenry", "AlanHenry",
  "AlanHenry", "Amistad", "Amistad", "Amistad", "Amistad", "Amistad",
  "Amistad", "Amistad", "AmonGCarter", "AmonGCarter", "AmonGCarter",
  "AmonGCarter", "AmonGCarter", "AmonGCarter"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  "1",
  "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13",
  "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"
))
```

Comment: This works for the dd data set but when I try to apply it to my data I get an error. Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `lag`.
x Problem with `mutate()` input `springmean`.
x Input `springmean` can't be recycled to size 2.
i Input `springmean` is `x[season == "spring"]`.
i Input `springmean` must be size 2 or 1, not 0.
i The error occurred in group 1: year = "2009".
i Input `lag` is `lag_spring(change, SeasonYear)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: year = "2009".

Comment: I tried to structure my dataframe exactly like yours `dd <- structure(list(SeasonYear = c(raw.WL.season$SeasonYear), 
                     change = c(raw.WL.season$change), 
                     Lake_name = c(raw.WL.season$Lake_name)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1:nrow(raw.WL.season)))` but I still get that error. I am wondering if you can help me figure out how to avoid that error.

Comment: Hi @DavidSmith. I just made an edit and slightly changed the function. One issue with my function was that it worked only if there is a lagged "spring". If that is not the case `x[season == "spring"]` will not work and will result in the error you got. Not sure whether this is indeed the issue but you could give it a try.

Comment: It works perfectly now! Thanks!